# Magento admin not showing any messages

Tags: error

Admin not showing succusses or error message.We have upgraded Magento2.2.8 to Magento2.3.7-p1

Comment: have you check console, is there any error there?

Comment: check the Magento logs and try to verify/login in the private window.

Comment: I have solved message issue.

I have checked in system.log file and find below error Error : main.WARNING: Session size of 371018 exceeded allowed session max size of 256000. I have run below command now error or sucusses messages is showing well. Solution : php bin/magento config:set system/security/max_session_size_admin 0

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue that is Store -> Config -> System -> Security -> Max Session Size in Admin if I make this 0 then started working.
I am not sure that it will impact on website admin panel speed.

Answer (score 0):

Please check in the system log file and find below message.

Like Error : main.WARNING: Session size of 371018 exceeded allowed session max size of 256000.

If you receive this type of error message so you can resolve this issue using two diffrent methods. That steps gave you below.

1. `php bin/magento config:set system/security/max_session_size_admin 0`
2. `Store -> Config -> Advanced -> System -> Security -> Max Session Size in Admin &&  Max Session Size in Storefront -> Set "0" -> Save Config.`